# How to filter content by date in Views?

Tags: views, 8

There is one date field = "Display-date" and my content is displaying as:

2016 | abc

2016 | def

2015 | pqr

2014 | wer

I'm applying a filter in view:

```
content:display-date
```

and set `its value = 2016` so that only 2016 year content will get visible. (as shown in below screenshot) I chose time zone = UTC.

This is giving me NULL results.

[image]

**How can I get only 2016 year result to get rendered?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use CCYY-MM-DD format

So use **is between** `2016-01-01` and `2017-01-01` which will print all 2016 nodes, don't worry, it will not print any 1st day of 2017 nodes. (tested it)

Use a group filter so you can change the name, if you expose the filter that is.

Comment: After doing some testing, updated my answer, as my original answer will not print the Dec 31st node.

Comment: @NoSssweat : *testing* is the art of "only believing what you've seen (to work) with your own eyes ...". Not to hijack your answer, but any idea why using Dec 31st did not work? If so, consider adding that to your answer also...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I have no idea, in my opinion the correct solution is not intuitive.

Comment: I've ***not*** tested this, but are you saying (and sure) that it will print the 1st day of 2016 then also (which is what I'd hope). In other words: are you saying that "in between" gets processed as "**on** or after 2016-01-01 AND before but **not on** 2017-01-01"? I mean: if jan 01 of 2017 would NOT be included, then why would jan 01 of 2016 be included? Maybe I'm missing something ... sorry.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens yes I was saying that, but now that I think about this again, perhaps I did not test this properly. If you see in screen shot, it says after HH:MM:SS, so I suppose if you leave this out it assumes `00:00:00`, so only Jan 1 2017 at time of `00:00:00` perhaps would show up. So perhaps a more accurate answer would be `2016-12-31 23:59:59`